# How to get values in an array from nested array of objects based on a given condition?

Tags: lodash

I'm using **lodash** and I have the following array of objects:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "values": [
        {
            "sub": "fr",
            "name": "foobar1"
        }, 
        {
            "sub": "en",
            "name": "foobar2"
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "id": 2,
    "values": [
        {
            "sub": "fr",
            "name": "foobar3"
        },
        {
            "sub": "en",
             "name": "foobar4"
        }
    ]
}]
```

What i'm trying to get the list of ID and name for a given "SUB".
So, with the previous object, if I send the sub *fr* I want to get:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foobar1"

}, 
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "foobar3"
}]
```

Do you know if I can easily do it with lodash?

I tried to use `_.pick` but it doesn't working(I'm a bit lost with these mixes between nested objects and arrays) `_.map(data, function (o) { _.pick(o, ['id', 'values.name']) });`.

I also tried to use `_.filter` with things like `_.filter(data, { values: [{ sub: 'fr' }]});` but it return all the items. What I'm looking for is to return the nested part only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [flatMap()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatMap) where its callback returns an array of filtered `subs` using [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) where each filtered item is transformed using [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map).

```
var result =  _.flatMap(data, item => 
  _(item.values)
    .filter({ sub: 'fr' })
    .map(v => ({id: item.id, name: v.name}))
    .value()
);
```

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "values": [
        {
            "sub": "fr",
            "name": "foobar1"
        }, 
        {
            "sub": "en",
            "name": "foobar2"
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "id": 2,
    "values": [
        {
            "sub": "fr",
            "name": "foobar3"
        },
        {
            "sub": "en",
             "name": "foobar4"
        }
    ]
}];

var result =  _.flatMap(data, item => 
  _(item.values)
    .filter({ sub: 'fr' })
    .map(v => ({id: item.id, name: v.name}))
    .value()
);
           
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, _.flatMap() seems really useful!

Answer (score 5):

following @ryeballar's answer, a shorter version with map

```
var result =  _.map(data, item => ({id: item.id, name: item.name}));
```